# Web page becomes unresponsive after several posts

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am fairly new to IIS.

Hello, I am experiencing a very strange error once I publish my ASP.NET webpage onto IIS. The page functions fine while browsing, which makes several SQL calls for the menus and information on the site. This works fine both while debugging and when it goes live.

My problem is that after the user has made a couple of POSTs to update information in the live version, the page becomes unresponsive, or shows extremely high latency and returns nothing of the SQL requests that it was supposed to call. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Are you closing sql connections when they finish?

Comment: Yes. Properly closing them with using and everything. The webpage works fine for an indeterminate amount of time so long as it is not submitting any information-

Comment: Maybe there are attacker bots that feed on naked connectionStrings? Are you using <%$ ... %> tag to access it for its safety?

Comment: I would never put my connection string directly into the html. This is all from code behind.

Comment: Post your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the server administrator forgot to give an application pool to the site. Hopefully this will help other people.